# On Android, what is the easiest way to print from Chrome browser to a Bluetooth mobile printer?

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

My web app creates a print dialogue on desktop and I am trying to see if there is away to do something similar via the mobile chrome browser. Any advice on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [Android Printing API](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iub67ic87KI) was added in Android 4.4 (KitKat) and supports printing to Google Cloud Print enabled printers out of the box (along with HP printers via the [HP Print Service app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hp.android.printservice)) - Chrome for Android has an option for printing the current web page from the overflow menu.

If the printer you are using is not supported, then you should urge the manufacturer (or an intrepid developer familiar with Bluetooth development and printer protocols) to create a plugin app and use the [android.printservice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/printservice/package-summary.html) API to add support for the printers.