# Printing to a bluetooth printer in a TAB from a web application

Tags: asp.net

I like to Know if there is any way for my web application to access the Bluetooth printer in an Android Phone.
My web application is developed in .NET and has been hosted in a server.

So far the printing is done with the server printer, but i am faced with a new requirement whereby i am required to print to the Bluetooth printer that has been paired to the android device.

Since the application is run in a web browser I do know that I can use
    window.print() in javascript but this has no effect in the web browser of the android device.

Comment: Describe your use-case; to me it looks like an XY-problem! -> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Thanks I  have added more details to the same

Comment: Looks like the duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007094/on-android-what-is-the-easiest-way-to-print-from-chrome-browser-to-a-bluetooth